# Need Suggestions for Video Player in Asp.Net Website

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, html, html5-video

I want to integrate a video player in asp.net web application which support most of formats like FLV, MP4,MOV,WAV,AVI,WEBM,OGG etc.

I tried to search via google. But I am not able to find out player which support most of video formats.

It would be great if video player does not required any plugin which must be installed in browser. I need JQuery or HTML5 Video Player.

Please give me suggestions which video player can supports most of video formats and works good.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [JPlayer](http://jplayer.org)

You can also try JW Player

I have used JPlayer as a music player and it is pretty solid.

Comment: But it supports only 3 Video formats  MP4, WebM and FLV. Please suggest other if you know.

Answer (score 0):

if using HTML5 then you can use this, but it will only work with HTML5 supported browsers.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">      
</video>
```